# Scared of praying because of fear of death

Tags: salat, death

Due to having some anxiety issues and being scared too easily, once I heard a man who died while praying jumah after which I became frightened even though death is a gift towards a new life. I am scared maybe because my imam is weak. Please give me the confidence to pray again through your advice. Whenever I try praying, I always get these evil thoughts so I can't continue and stop and cry.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 0):

Everybody knows they are going to die one day, but they choose to ignore the fact. It's good that you acknowledge the fact and always remember that. However knowing this fact brings a question, "If it's inevitable, what can I do to make it worth dying ?" and the answer is to live a righteous and meaningful life. There is not greater meaning than worshiping the one who created you and the one whom you will return. The Best form of death is passing away while you are in the middle of this act.

Think about the real meaning of life brother and remember it's just the deception of the devil. If you know all these facts there is no reason for you to be scared. If you are scared because of your sins, take action and pray more for the mercy of Allah. Allah is the most merciful.

Allah knows the best !

Answer (score 0):

Assalam-u-Alaikum

Brother these are waswas from shaitan don't  listen to these thoughts ALLAH has already decreed the time for your death when you were not even born.Nothing will happen to you until ALLAH wills.Just put your trust in ALLAH